# Custom ViewPager Horizontal Swiping Theme/Syle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

I am sorry if this is really a simple question but I am new into this. I am using a ViewPager and fragments for my app which swipes the page normally as shown in the following animation
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

But I want something more fancy just like in the book or something similar. I have searched a lot but didn't find anything useful. For the simple swiping I have the following

```
public class ManmohanSingh extends FragmentActivity {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
static ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.manmohan_singh);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment manmohanAng = new ManmohanAng(position);
        return manmohanAng;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1431;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1431; i++) {
            if (position == i) {
                return "Ang " + position;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://www.androidviews.net/2013/02/jazzyviewpager/

If it doesn't have the animation you need, you can look into to the source to see how it's done.